# Rails: Trouble referncing a model from within a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

From the console I can do this:

```
bin = Bin.find(9)       
bin.messages.create :to => "joe@example.com", :from => "tom@example.com", :subject => "hi", :body => "just hi"
```

However, I'm trying to do the exact same thing from within a function in my Message model and it's saving a record however the bin_id is nil. This is important because Message belongs to a Bin and a Bin has many Messages.

Contents of message.rb:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :from, :subject, :to
    belongs_to :bin
    def self.receive_mail(message)
        bin = Bin.find(9)       
        bin.messages.create :to => "joe@example.com", :from => "tom@example.com", :subject => "hi", :body => "just hi"
    end
end
```

Is there something special I need to do to get the Bin from within my Message model?

Comment: Why do you pass `message` as an argument? Pass `bin` and then use `bin.messages.create...`

Comment: Oh. You showed me how to solve it! Passing "message" in was confusing the model. I changed the name of the variable to something else and it's working. Thanks!